# Add Items to an object vector based on a condition on the member variable

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors of custom object defined as follows

```
struct PrimitiveInfo
{
    std::list<int> symbolNumbers;
    //other attributes here....
};
```

I have these two vectors

```
std::vector<PrimitiveInfo> m_symbolPrimitiveList;
std::vector<PrimitiveInfo> m_newPrimitiveList;
```

These two vectors gets populated by other methods with Data.

Now I want to Add the `m_newPrimitiveList` items that have different symbolNumbers than the ones in `m_symbolPrimitiveList`

For Eg: if a new primitivelist object contains symbolNumbers as `1,2,3` I need to add this object to the `m_symbolPrimitiveList` vector only if it doesn't have an object that has symbolnumbers as `1,2,3` in their list. If it has an object with symbolnumbers `1,2,3` I wouldn't add new object to `m_symbolPrimitiveList`.

This could be done through for loops, but I want to know if there's a smarter way to achieve this? I am not using C++ 11

Comment: How do you need to check the list? i.e. what if `m_symbolPrimitiveList` already has symbolnumbers as `1,2,3,4` in your example?

Comment: Such case where `m_symbolprimitivelist` has a superset of the new primitive list doesnt exist. I mean i am verifying and reporting an error before this function. So we can safely assume that newprimitive list should match exactly the symbol numbers in that of `m_symbolprimitivelist`

Comment: Did you try to use `std::find` and `std::find_if` methods? It can help you to reduce number of loops

Comment: So, I tried using `std::find` with objects on single level, meaning. if I want to find something in an object list. But this case is different where I want to match the list of integers which is inside an object and which is a vector. Hence not sure how to entend that and thus posted here to get more insight

Comment: "I am not using C++ 11 "  Which C++ are you using then? C++98?

Comment: I believe its c++ 2003

Comment: There are probably many ways to do what you want... but it is not clear enough how we should check the list. Could items be sorted? Do you want exact match, subset, superset? How many items you could have in a list? In the vector? I would probably use a `std::set` and lexical comparison...

Comment: If you are not using C++ 11, then consider upgrading. You are using 20 years old compiler which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for your case. You may want to change this code as per your needs, especially part where list of numbers are checked

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public:
    list<int> numbers;
    friend bool operator== (const MyStruct& p1, const MyStruct& p2);
};

bool operator== (const MyStruct& p1, const MyStruct& p2)
{
    // change as you want to check if objects are equal
    list<int> l1 = p1.numbers;
    list<int> l2 = p2.numbers;
    for (list<int>::const_iterator it1=l1.begin(); it1 != l1.end(); ++it1) {
        list<int>::iterator it2 = find(l2.begin(), l2.end(), *it1);
        if (it2 != p2.numbers.end()) {
            // at least one element is found, treat it as equal
            cout << "equal " << *it1 << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    cout << "not equal" << endl;
    return false;
}

bool checkInfo(MyStruct info, vector<MyStruct> v2)
{
    bool found = false;
    vector<MyStruct>::iterator it = find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), info);
    // true if info is found in v2
    return it != v2.end();
}
```

And usage would be:

```
vector<MyStruct> s1;
vector<MyStruct> s2;

list<int> l1;
l1.push_back(1);
l1.push_back(2);

MyStruct p1;
p1.numbers = l1;
s2.push_back(p1);
s2.push_back(p1);

for (int i =0; i < s2.size(); i++) {
    if (checkInfo(s2[i], s1)) {
        // found, do not add
        cout << "found. skipp adding" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not found, so need to add " << endl;
        s1.push_back(s2[i]);
    }
}
```